# Given $L=\{(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) \in \Bbb C^{n} : Re_{z_i}-Im_{z_i}=0, i=1,...n\}$, find some basis of some direct complement of L in real vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $L=\{(z_1,z_2,...,z_n) \in \Bbb C^{n} : Re_{z_i}-Im_{z_i}=0, i=1,...n\}$, find some basis of some direct complement of L in real vector space.

First things first, how   do I even find the basis of L?

Answer (score 0):

Your $L$ is not a subspace of $ \mathbb C^n$ !

We have $L=\{(1+i)(x_1,...,x_n): x_1,...,x_n \in \mathbb R\}$

Therefore $z:=(1+i)(1,...,1) \in L$ but $iz \notin L$